# I want to rbind 2 rows but without overlapping rows in R

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, rbind

I have `data1` and `data2`.

```
data1 <- data.frame(date = c(123, 124, 125, 126),
                    peter = c(10, 11, NA, NA),
                    turner = c(20, 21, NA, NA))

data2 <- data.frame(date = c(124, 125, 126, 127, 128),
                    peter = c(12, 10, 30, 50, 70),
                    turner = c(23, 20, 40, 60, 80))
```

My goal is to `rbind` `data1` and `data2`. However, as you can see, `date` overlaps .I have to make sure that when I bind them, `date` has to be not overlapped. So, I want to use the non-overlapping rows from `data1` and use the other rows from `data2` and rbind them together. In this example, `date`=124,125,126 overlaps. So,my desired output should look like this:

```
data=data.frame(date=c(123,124,125,126,127,128), peter=c(10,12,10,30,50,70), turner=c(20,23,20,40,60,80))
```

I don't know how to do in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want `dplyr::rows_upsert()` which adds new rows or overwrites existing rows by key:

```
library(dplyr)

rows_upsert(data1, data2, by = "date")

  date peter turner
1  123    10     20
2  124    12     23
3  125    10     20
4  126    30     40
5  127    50     60
6  128    70     80
```